# What is the difference between ISession.SaveOrUpdateCopy() and ISession.Merge()?

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-3

In NHibernate 3.1, `ISession.SaveOrUpdateCopy()` has been marked as deprecated. The documentation suggests using `Merge()` instead. The documentation for each is as follows:

#### `SaveOrUpdateCopy(object obj)`

> Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with
>   the session, it will be loaded. Return the persistent instance. If the
>   given instance is unsaved or does not exist in the database, save it and
>   return it as a newly persistent instance. Otherwise, the given instance
>   does not become associated with the session.

#### `Merge(object obj)`

> Copy the state of the given object onto the persistent object with the same
>   identifier. If there is no persistent instance currently associated with
>   the session, it will be loaded. Return the persistent instance. If the
>   given instance is unsaved, save a copy of and return it as a newly persistent
>   instance. The given instance does not become associated with the session.
>   This operation cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped
>   with `cascade="merge"`.
>   The semantics of this method are defined by JSR-220.

They look nearly identical to me, but there are bound to be some subtleties involved. If so, what are they?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**SaveOrUpdateCopy** is now considered obsolete and thus **Merge** is meant to take over for it (hence its extreme similarity).

They are pretty much the same except I don't think those cascade options were available with **SaveOrUpdateCopy**.  However, that point is moot as **Merge** should be method you use.

---

**UPDATE**: I went in to the source code of NHibernate just to make sure they are as similar as I was thinking and here is what I found.

Both **Merge** and **SaveOrUpdateCopy** have very similar implementations:

```
public object Merge(string entityName, object obj)
{
    using (new SessionIdLoggingContext(SessionId))
    {
        return FireMerge(new MergeEvent(entityName, obj, this));
    }
}

public object SaveOrUpdateCopy(object obj)
{
    using (new SessionIdLoggingContext(SessionId))
    {
        return FireSaveOrUpdateCopy(new MergeEvent(null, obj, this));
    }
}
```

Their **FireXXXX** methods are also very similar:

```
private object FireMerge(MergeEvent @event)
{
    using (new SessionIdLoggingContext(SessionId))
    {
        CheckAndUpdateSessionStatus();
        IMergeEventListener[] mergeEventListener = listeners.MergeEventListeners;
        for (int i = 0; i < mergeEventListener.Length; i++)
        {
            mergeEventListener[i].OnMerge(@event);
        }
        return @event.Result;
    }
}

private object FireSaveOrUpdateCopy(MergeEvent @event)
{
    using (new SessionIdLoggingContext(SessionId))
    {
        CheckAndUpdateSessionStatus();
        IMergeEventListener[] saveOrUpdateCopyEventListener = listeners.SaveOrUpdateCopyEventListeners;
        for (int i = 0; i < saveOrUpdateCopyEventListener.Length; i++)
        {
            saveOrUpdateCopyEventListener[i].OnMerge(@event);
        }
        return @event.Result;
    }
}
```

The methods are exactly the same except they draw on different event listener lists, but even the types of the lists (**IMergeEventListener**) are the same!

Looking at the listener lists, they are both initialized with a default listener.  The default listener for the **Merge** listen handlers is of type **DefaultMergeEventListener** while the **SaveOrUpdateCopy** is **DefaultSaveOrUpdateCopyEventListener**.  Thus, the difference between them is just the difference in these two implementations (that is if you keep the default listener, which is 99% of the time).

However, the real interesting fact **IS** the difference in implementation.  If you look at **DefaultSaveOrUpdateCopyEventListener** you get this:

```
public class DefaultSaveOrUpdateCopyEventListener : DefaultMergeEventListener
{
    protected override CascadingAction CascadeAction
    {
        get { return CascadingAction.SaveUpdateCopy; }
    }
}
```

This means the default behavior for **Merge** and **SaveOrUpdateCopy** only differs in the cascading actions, everything else is exactly the same.